# SQL code update table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have two tables:

```
Master Table       Assets Table
-AssetNo-           -AssetNo-
```

`AssetNo` is the PK, and it's a foreign key to link the two tables. Now, I'd like to update using:

```
UPDATE Assets 
   SET status = 1
  FROM Assets, Master
 WHERE Assets.AssetNo = Master.AssetNo
```

If I use this command, all asset with the same `assetno` will automatic update to 1.

How to code with specific `assetNo` IE: `WHERE 111(from Assets)=111(from Master)`

Comment: The syntax for multi-table updates differs from one database product to next.  What SQL product are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you just need another condition in your WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE Assets 
   SET status = 1
  FROM Assets, Master
 WHERE Assets.AssetNo = Master.AssetNo
   AND Assets.AssetNo = 111
```

Answer (score 1):

What sql engine are you using? Something like this would work for sql server:

```
Update a
SET Status = 1
FROM Assets a
JOIN Master m on a.AssetNo = m.AssetNo
WHERE a.AssetNo  = 111
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Assets SET status = 1
FROM Assets a JOIN Master m ON a.AssetNo = m.AssetNo
WHERE a.AssetNo = 999
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Status = 1
FROM Assets AS a
INNER JOIN Master AS m ON a.AssetNo = m.AssetNo
WHERE m.AssetNo = @value
```

Comment: how to add value ya ..i have this Request.Form("AssetNo").

Comment: What language are you using to talk to the database? What is the version of SQL you are using?

Comment: ASP classic and SQL server 2000